# How make data entry using autogenerated texboxes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm asking a simple question on how to do data entry when using a custom number of textboxes.  Usualy, in books, or tutorials, we consider a fixed number of entries for the controller.  But what if the number of entries varies?

For a concrete example, imagine some number of products which we need to enter quantity.  How to manage this if one time we have 3 products and the other time we have 10 products?

Thank you.